# How to convert object file to JSON with JS

Tags: javascript, json

i'm creating WP app with HTML, CSS and Javascripts, now i have a question: 
- I using openPicker.pickSingleFileAndContinue() to pick a picture from library and i create a file from it:

```
var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(filePicked);
```

I use console.log(file), it print:

```
[object File]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      constructor: { },
      lastModifiedDate: [date] Thu Apr 02 2015 16:44:58,
      name: "WP_20150402_001.jpg",
      size: 1048405,
      type: "image/jpeg"
   }
```

Now, my question is: How can i convert it to JSON file with format:

```
{file:
 [
  {
    modified: date] Thu Apr 02 2015 16:44:58,
    name: "WP_20150402_001.jpg",
    size: 1048405,
    type: "image/jpeg"
  }
 ]
}
```

Tks for read, plz help me.

Comment: If I am correct you want to convert this object instance to a JSON string you can write to the filesystem?

Comment: Do you have control over File constructor or is it some native one? However in any case you will be able to implement toJson method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(filePicked);

// Create POJO structured like the way we want.
var fileData = {
  file: {
    modified: file.lastModifiedDate,
    name: file.name,
    size: file.size,
    type: file.type
  }
}

// Convert data to JSON string.
var serializedData = JSON.stringify(fileData);
```

`serializedData` should now contain something like the following value:

```
"{"file":{"lastModifiedDate":"2015-04-02T10:52:31.993Z","name":"WP_20150402_001.jpg","size":1048405,"type":"image/jpeg"}}"
```